# How to show image to pdf generated by jsPDF library in titanium/android appcelerator

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator, jspdf

Can we add an image to a pdf generated by the jsPDF library in titanium/android? Simple text is printing nicely but want to know is there any way of adding and displaying image in generated pdf. Here is the small example i am using:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you not like that test2?');

var res = doc.output();

var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'auther.pdf');
file.write(res);
var pdfview = Ti.UI.createWebView({width:'100%',height:'100%',data:file});
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
win.add(pdfview);
```

Comment: Wer you able to add image in pdf